# iOS - Unknown Bug In Random Number Generation?

Tags: ios, arc4random

I'm trying to put some objects in the screen at random positions.

I use arc4random() to generate a new random number.

But it seems that the function is not working properly, here's the code and traced result:

```
Code :

UIView *stateView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( (arc4random()%700)-100 , (20 * 91) + 378 + ((arc4random()%600)+200), 325 , 188)];

NSLog(@"Note %d : X = %f , Y = %f",i,stateView.frame.origin.x,stateView.frame.origin.y);


**********************


NSLog Output :

Note 5 : X = 4294967040.000000 , Y = 2552.000000
```

Is this a bug or I'm doing wrong with the generator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation for `arc4random()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html), the return type is `u_int32_t`, which is an unsigned type. In the expression

```
(arc4random()%700)-100
```

the calculation, including the subtraction, is done using *unsigned* arithmetic. You are getting unsigned arithmetic overflow. To fix this, cast to a signed integer type before doing the subtraction:

```
((int) (arc4random() % 700)) - 100
```

The result of this will be an integer from -100 through 599.